# Android Studio, LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /foo/bar/include not working?

Tags: android, c, android-studio, android-ndk

I have an Android Studio project that uses NDK
and I can't get include paths to work.

let say I have app/src/main/jni/foo/bar/file.c

and it includes "my/lib/inc.h"

When I add

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/user/include/  (to app/src/main/jni/Android.mk)

where the folder "my" is located I still get file not found from ndk-build

If I add "my" to app/src/main/jni it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you invoking NDK-build from the command line, or via Android Studio?  In the later case it may be generating its own Android.mk and ignoring yours.

Comment: I'm invoking through Android Studio. How do I check if it uses its own Android.mk?

Comment: It seems to be the case that ndk-build invoked from Android Studio generates and uses an Android.mk in "app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug"

Comment: Yes, Android Studio's gradle plugin ignore your Android.mk. Instead it generate own Android.mk on the fly. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609188/android-ndk-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-on-sample-hello-jni/29609729#29609729) I've described more detailed how it works and how to workaround it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio is probably ignoring your Android.mk and generating its own.

At the present instant in time, the NDK isn't well supported by Android Studio, and although you will find various version-specific gradle rule modifications which have apparently worked for their authors, it may be easier build the NDK code yourself and merely let the packaging stage pickup the results.